# React Native: Remover função goBack() do botão físico do Android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Preciso remover a Ação de voltar telas do botão físico do Android em determinado momento. Basicamente, tenho um método que mostra meu SearchBar, enquanto o SearchBar estiver visível, preciso que a ação de voltar telas seja desabilitada, e no lugar dela, seja habilitado um outro método que tenho que oculta  o SearchBar. Após oculta-lo, preciso ativar a função de voltar telas novamente. Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
// oculta o header, exibe o searchbar
hideHeader () {

    /* código.... */

    /* Aqui tento remover a função de voltar tela e adicionar a função de 
    ocultar o SearchBar, no botão físico */
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backButtonClick);
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.hideSearchBar);
}

// oculta SearchBar,  mostra header
hideSearchBar () {

    /* código.... */

    /* Aqui, removo a função que adicionei para desativar o this.props.navigation.goBack() */
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backButtonClick)
}

// adiciona ou remove a função this.props.navigation.goBack()
backButtonClick(){
    if(this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.goBack){
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Consigo abrir o SearchBar normalmente, o problema é quando pressiono o botão do Android "Voltar", já que o SearchBar está visível, ele deveria somente oculta-lo. Mas além de ocultar, ele volta pra tela anterior.

Se alguém puder ajudar fico agradecido!

Answer (score 1):

Quando o evento de `hardwareBackPress` é disparado ou você volta para a tela anterior da sua Stack ou você cancela através de condições. Por exemplo, crie uma variável que indicará se o campo se search esta aberto ou fechado. Assim quando você pressionar o botão de `Voltar` do celular ele fara a verificação e decidira qual ação terá de fazer.

```
state={
    searchOpen: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        this.backButtonClick();
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
}

// adiciona ou remove a função this.props.navigation.goBack()
backButtonClick() {
    if (this.state.searchOpen) {

        this.setState({ searchOpen: false });

        return false;
    }

    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);

    return true;
}
```